# Ubuntu qemu Display output to logfile

Tags: server, virtualization, qemu

we install our Ubuntu 20.04.3 with packer and qemu. Since we are working without a display output, the question now is whether it would be possible to put the output into a log file.

We activated the qemu and packer debug log, unfortunately we don't get any display output and couldn't track where the nographic installation is at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

To get all into a file you'd usually want to create a muxing chardev and assign all outputs to it that you want.

```
  -chardev stdio,mux=on,logfile=guest.log,id=char0 \
  -mon chardev=char0,mode=readline \
  -serial chardev:char0
```

You can decide to not put the monitor on that, or to pass them to different files and so on. All up to you. For details see "Character device options" in `man qemu` [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/qemu-system.1.html).